# Defining a shard-key automatically for a dynamic collection and suggestion on the design

Tags: mongodb, sharding

I want to implement Sharding for my MongoDb and need some of your suggestions.

**Insight**

1. We have lots of cron-job which collects various information about a machine & writes them to it's own collection.
2. Collections are created dynamically.
3. Each collection has millions of data.
4. Structure1 for each collection is Name, Category, Subcategory, NodeId, Process-Start-Time, Process-End-Time, Value.
5. Structure2 for each collection is Name, Category, Subcategory, Subtype, Date, Value.
6. Structure3 for each collection is Name, Category, Subcategory, NodeId, Process-Start-Time, Process-End-Time, Value, Flag1, Flag2, Flag3.

After a research we found we will use sharding and make it useful with multiple servers which guarantees two things:

1. Need not worry on running out of space.
2. Balanced performance across servers

> **Question 1:**
> My problem is to find a correct shard-key to partition the data. I don't see a unique-key in the collection other than the default ObjectId. After further reading I have found that it is possible to use a composite key, does it make sense to have a composite key or custom ObjectId as a key where the value might look like ObjectId: _. This is very key with respect to performance of returning the results of a query & moving the chunks.
>
> **Question 2:**
> Since we have large collections, it will become difficult to set the shard each time in Mongo console when a collection is created dynamically. Is there any way to make it automatic in mongo so that whenever a collection is created for a shard-database, it will define the shard-key for that collection?
>
> **Question 3:**
> Is it really necessary to pass shard-key to the query expression? I don't think we have used ObjectId in any of our query-expression, I doubt I can come with a unique ID due to fact that the data is not structured like a traditional DB. If yes, how is it going to help for a query like this:

**Example:**

> { category: "Energy", subcategory: "Watt", Process-Start-Time: {$gte: 132234234}}

Thanks in advance for stepping in and helping me fix this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to do this might be to shard the database, but leave the collections unsharded.  Benefits:

- Collections will be distributed across the shards (but each collection will only live on one shard). *EDIT: I was wrong about this, this isn't implemented yet.  See [the related Jira ticket](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-939) to track.  For now, you can use [tags](http://www.kchodorow.com/blog/2012/07/25/controlling-collection-distribution/) to distribute collections, but not automatically.*
- No need to call shardCollection on each new collection

The downside is that all traffic for a collection will go to its shard, which might be impractical for what you're trying to do.

As far as your questions:

Question 1: Shard key does not have to be unique.  What are you generally querying for?  You might be better of with something like `{category:1}` or `{category:1,subcategory:1}`.

Question 2: No built-in way to do it automatically, the best way to get that behavior is probably to set up a cron job.

Question 3: No.  Queries containing the shard key can be sent to specific shards and queries without the shard key must be sent to all shards, see http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Sharding+Introduction#ShardingIntroduction-OperationTypes.

Comment: Thanks for valuable information, if I just shard the database and leave collection unsharded, say I have 30 collections and have two shard servers, then how does Mongo divide the chunks/collections in to these shard-servers? Like you said each collection will only live on one shard, that means I should have only two collections?

Comment: No, it should put 15 collections on each shard.