# Implement Mongodb sharding in the Database level and leaving collections unsharded

Tags: mongodb, sharding

I am Trying to implement sharding on our mongoDB data base , Here is the scenario

we have 1 server running config server

we have 2 servers running mongod instances called node1 and node2

We have 1 server running mongos

I have added the servers node1 and node2 as shard servers in the mongos shell by using the command

db.runCommand( { addshard : "serverhostname[:port]" } );

later I created database in node1 and enabled sharding for that database from Mongos

Now we have 2 shard servers and as per MongoDB documentation mongos should put some collections which are created node1 ( where the database actually resides ) and some collections on node 2 .

I created 300 collections from mongos but still all collections are going to only one server what is wrong in the above mentioned support

NOTE : - Since I am not in a position to upgrade the application layer I cant shard in collection level , I have a script which creates several collections dynamically for some requirement .

Please Provide your suggestions on how we can shard in database level so that collections gets equally distributed among all shard servers .

I am looking for some solution like

IF i create 300 collections automatically mongos should create around 150 or 100 collections in each of the two sharded servers .

Thanks in advance for stepping in and helping me fix this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Collections are not automatically distributed across shards until you [enable sharding](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Configuring+Sharding#ConfiguringSharding-ShardingaCollection) on them and then add data.  Those sharded collections will then have data on both shards (split into chunks and balanced automatically).

Until you actually run the command on the collections, and have enough data in them so that they start splitting and migrating chunks, then they will all stay where they are.

That is because each database has a primary shard, which does not change.  That is where the database will be created initially and where all of its non-sharded data will live.  If you add another database, the mongos should create it on the second shard and alternate (or round robin if more than two) for each created database.  In each case, until you shard the collection, it will stay solely on the primary shard for that database.

Comment: Thank you for the valuable information Adam , But we are dynamically creating collections lets say daily around 300 collections what to do in this case how to shard the things if we shard in the collection level , we will end up sharding several hundred collections . we need to shard in the DB level only . Is there any alternative for this kind of scenario where collections gets created  ( say for each user of website ) daily .

Comment: That is not really how sharding works in MongoDB, and there is no way to automatically do what you describe.  You could create 2 databases so that there is at least one database on each shard and then alternate or round robin through them when creating databases so that they are split evenly, but there would be no automatic balancing and no way to easily add another shard

Comment: Hey thats really a very good suggestion , I referred to the answer which was given by kristina a mongodb developer , here she says it happens but it is not happening for us [Stack overflow posting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10329484/defining-a-shard-key-automatically-for-a-dynamic-collection-and-suggestion-on-th)

Comment: actually if you read Kristina's answer (I work with her as it happens), you will notice she is saying the same thing: "each collection will only live on one shard" - i.e. collections that are unsharded will live in only one place.  Her answer to question 2 is basically what I said about the fact that you have to enable sharding (that is when you define the shard key, and it has to be done explicitly).

Comment: Thank you very much Adam for clarifying my confusion , It was a great help

Comment: After looking at Adams Valuable information , I referred To Kristina's Personal Blog , She has replied saying there is a new feature called tags , here is the link where she has explained about tags , I have not tested this but looks like this is the most feasible solution what I had expected [Controlling collection distribution](http://www.kchodorow.com/blog/2012/07/25/controlling-collection-distribution/ ) Thank you Kristina and Adam

Comment: I think this featre might help you in the future:
https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-939